# Where can I find the boot log?

Tags: boot, log, plymouth

When I boot up Ubuntu and I don't have the graphical boot screen (Plymouth) enabled I see a bunch of text saying if an action was [OK] or it [FAILED].

Since this process is a bit quick I can't fully read everything, but I would like to know what happens exactly.

I think there must be a log file somewhere where all this is written down.

But where?

Comment: `journalctl -b`. From the docs: _"Show messages from a specific boot. [...] The argument may be empty, in which case logs for the current boot will be shown."_

Comment: Same question on ServerFault: [*All Debian boot messages*](https://serverfault.com/q/516411).

Answer (score 28):

To see information from your most recent boot, run

```
journalctl -b
```

To see the details that were logged during a previous boot, just in case you need to compare them with your most recent, run

```
journalctl --list-boots
```

You will then see results similar to the output shown below, but will need to page to the bottom of the output to see the most recent.

```
-2 5d45a92d9d5a42d8ae1c8b454f7e1314 Sun 2018-08-19 02:29:21 PDT—Sun 2018-08-19 02:36:26 PDT

-1 d5b8ebc236734ee69c48c3809ae452b1 Sun 2018-08-19 02:43:06 PDT—Sun 2018-08-19 07:20:54 PDT

 0 6f844406186e4e31ba0375a7bc736242 Sun 2018-08-19 10:43:31 PDT—Sun 2018-08-19 18:54:51 PDT
```

At the very bottom of the output, you will see a line that starts with 0, which will represent your most recently logged boot info, the same info you saw when you ran journalctl -b.

To see the data that was logged during the previous boot, copy the identifier from the line that starts with -1 and run the following

```
journalctl --boot=d5b8ebc236734ee69c48c3809ae452b1
```

To go back further in time, just change to -2, -3, -4, etc.

Comment: You can use the number (0, -1, -2...) instead of the long boot identifier.

Answer (score 5):

The log is in /var/log/boot.log. I set up a startup command on my system when I log in that opens a terminal and does "more /var/log/boot.log so each time I log in, I can check if there are any issues. If you only want to see failed lines, you can make it read:

```
grep FAILED /var/log/boot.log : more
```

which will show only lines with the word FAILED in them.

Note that /var/log/boot.log only shows the log of the startup commands, not the complete boot prior to that point.

Answer (score 1):

The log file in question is `/var/log/boot.log`. This contains in particular the messages you are seeking.

Comment: I have don't have a file named boot.log in /var/log .