# Xubuntu 18.04 freezes constantly requiring a hard reboot

Tags: boot, 18.04, xubuntu, freeze

I had asked this question before [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396339&).
Still having problems, and I don't know where to start.
It just froze again, and I shutdown the HP 15 Notebook laptop.
I'm now on my old laptop to preserve any logs that were left behind as it was frozen.

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 from a live USB stick, I can boot up with USB, and grab any logs before I restart it from the hard drive if helps.
Let me know what you need from me to make this question more answerable.
I'm a complete noob, and have read other threads about Xubuntu freezing, but it would be so much easier if someone can point me to the right log that would help diagnose the problem.

I'm able to use my PC sometimes for a few hours, sometimes it will freeze after a few minutes. Usually while I'm browsing the web with Chromium. I have uploaded my syslog to [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/35Hv7iRY). Hopefully this is what is needed to further help diagnose this problem.

This *ACPI BIOS Error* bug is found 34 times in the syslog:

```
Oct  3 01:38:19 PC kernel: [111095.265922] ACPI BIOS Error (bug):       
 Failure looking up [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._Q33.PMIN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
```

Results of `inxi -F` :

```
$ inxi -F
System:    Host: PC Kernel: 4.17.0-041700-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: HP product: HP 15 Notebook PC v: Type1 - ProductConfigId serial: N/A
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 233F v: 06.27 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Insyde v: F.35 date: 04/25/2017
Battery    BAT0: charge: 29.1 Wh 100.0% condition: 29.1/29.1 Wh (100%)
CPU:       Quad core Intel Pentium N3540 (-MCP-) cache: 1024 KB
           clock speeds: max: 2665 MHz 1: 1419 MHz 2: 620 MHz 3: 499 MHz
           4: 499 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Bay Trail version: 4.2 Mesa 18.0.5
Audio:     Card Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.17.0-041700-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: rtl8188ee
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: d4:6a:6a:0f:4d:6c
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCIE Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169
           IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: 48:ba:4e:51:23:57
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (30.8% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD5000LPCX size: 500.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 19G used: 5.4G (32%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: /home size: 196G used: 131G (71%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 8.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%)
           fs: swap dev: /dev/sda7
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 185 Uptime: 11 min Memory: 1060.6/3835.2MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

After [finding the boot log](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995711/where-can-i-find-the-boot-log) and scrolling through that log, these are the last two entries before the PC froze:

```
Oct 3 18:07:49 PC systemd-timesyncd[572]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com). 
Oct 3 18:09:26 PC systemd-resolved[570]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.43.1
```

Comment: This [Intel document](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/atom/atom-z36xxx-z37xxx-spec-update.html) contains some possible reasons why the Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx and Z37xxx Series freezes. This might help you to diagnose the problem if you have access to the right log files.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and adding additional information. What log file should I post here for further help, that intel document didn't tell me what to do to fix the problem.

Comment: [Where can I find the boot log?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995711/where-can-i-find-the-boot-log) (it works in 18.04) works from the virtual console: [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui/917386#917386) even if you can't boot to the desktop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I'm able to use my pc sometimes for a few hours, sometimes it will freeze after a few minutes. Usually while I'm browsing the web with chromium. I have uploaded syslog to pastebin, hopefully this is what is needed to further help diagnose this problem. https://pastebin.com/35Hv7iRY

Comment: After scrolling through that log, These are the last two entries before the pc froze: Oct  3 18:07:49 PC systemd-timesyncd[572]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct  3 18:09:26 PC systemd-resolved[570]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.43.1.

Comment: Just froze up again, I copied syslog to pastebin again after reboot https://pastebin.com/0iH5BcsM

Comment: This is probably the same issue as reported here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

Answer (score 0):

I have seen same issues on my Lenovo Thinkpad and a desktop computer.
I have found, that [baloo](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Baloo/) service has often high CPU usage and the computer was not responsable ..

So i have disabled baloo with `balooctl disable`, after restart it works without problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I searched for baloo on task manager and didn't see it, maybe we are using different distros? I'm running xubuntu 18.04 with the 4.17 Kernel. Here's a screenshot of Task manager sorted by Virtual bytes. https://imgur.com/a/0uRjidw

Comment: Please scroll down in task-manager. Your picture display's not the full list of tasks.
Test the command `balooctl disable` in console, its not dangerous if you have no baloo service..