# how do i enable boot logging on ubuntu?

Tags: boot, logging, logs

perhaps its server envy, but I am looking around on a linux server hard drive and saw a file called "bootlog" which holds entries like:

```
boot        Sat May  5 02:50:51 2018
shutdown    Thu May 31 22:59:24 2018
boot        Thu May 31 23:00:39 2018
shutdown    Tue Feb 12 23:40:23 2019
boot        Tue Feb 12 23:41:45 2019
shutdown    Tue Feb 12 23:53:43 2019
boot        Tue Feb 12 23:55:05 2019
**UNCLEAN RESTART**
boot        Sat Feb 23 14:40:09 2019
**UNCLEAN RESTART**
boot        Mon Apr 22 19:14:31 2019
shutdown    Fri Apr 26 08:32:39 2019
boot        Fri Apr 26 08:34:01 2019
shutdown    Thu May  2 10:00:09 2019
boot        Thu May  2 10:00:58 2019
**UNCLEAN RESTART**
boot        Thu May 16 09:27:43 2019
shutdown    Sun Sep 15 22:59:01 2019
boot        Sun Sep 15 23:00:22 2019
shutdown    Sun Dec  1 09:03:10 2019
boot        Sun Dec  1 09:03:57 2019
shutdown    Tue Jul  7 00:25:31 2020
boot        Tue Jul  7 00:26:21 2020
```

I thought that was pretty neat, and Im wondering how I too can get this functionality in Ubuntu.
My OS is ubuntu mate 20.04, and the source of this bootlog thing is from some OS branded as UTWOS. I cant find much info outside of that, and the hardware that boots this disk is currently borked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `last` command for similar output.
You can also use `journalctl --list-boots` as mentioned in this previous answer [Where can I find the boot log?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995711/where-can-i-find-the-boot-log)