# New Linux User Boot Screen Displaying Some Errors

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, intel, error-handling

Good morning folks,

I am new to Linux and am currently using Ubuntu 22.04. Currently I strictly run a Linux only environment on my laptop, got rid of Windows. However on the booting up the laptop I do notice a black screen filled with maybe around 5-10 missing or error messages which is viewable to me for less than a second.

My question is how can I figure out what drivers I may be missing or what errors are being thrown. Linux is working, but my OCD wishes to get rid of that screen with errors...

I would assume the specs of my computer matter and therefore I have a
Acer Nitro 5
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5
Memory: 16gb DDR4
GPU: 3050Ti M

Comment: helpful? https://vitux.com/view-system-log-files-ubuntu/

Comment: See the answers to [Where can I find boot logs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995711/where-can-i-find-the-boot-log) When you find the log entries, copy and paste them [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425981/edit) and format the pasted lines as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Very thanks @24601

Comment: You may find [the answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367947/acpi-error-messages-during-boot) helpful.

Comment: Just want to point out that if everything otherwise works properly, the errors are normal and not worrisome, and you likely will not be able to fix them without a firmware upgrade from the motherboard manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

During boot up you can control what is displayed ... open up a terminal ( ctrl + alt + t ) and issue

```
cat /etc/default/grub
```

and look for the line which starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`  does that line look like this :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

if not then edit that file and add those attributes to that line ( leave alone any existing attributes on that line ) ... one way to edit

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

if you needed to do above edit then after saving engage that change by doing

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```